# How to free transform a work path -thus the text inside it- in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, path, creative-cloud, text-wrap

I guess this is a really simple quest but I couldn't find the answer in Google.

I make a rectangular selection, right click, then choose "Make Work Path".

- so I have a rectangular path

Then click **T** icon (for text), type something in the path. It wraps the text nicely. Also adding dashes as word-breaks etc.

- so I have text inside the path.

But one problem is, I want to modify the path (say, make it wider but shorter). I can select the path and transform it, but the text remains the same.

How can I transform the path, and also the text in it, so that the text wraps to the new path accordingly ?

What I currently do is, create the new path, type the text again. Which can cost a lot of time for so many small changes.

So I really want to find a way to change the path, that is wrapping the text, without changing the text itself.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out.

That's why I love asking it to stackexchange. And hopefully I will help someone too.

The answer is, direct selection tool.

The tool that has the mouse cursor. Above the rectangle (or, 5th from bottom) in Photoshop CS3.

You click on the path with the direct selection tool. You choose 1 or more vertices (corners), you drag them. The text follows the path.